# How to downsample a point cloud while maintaining its order? (PCL C++)

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I want to downsample incoming pointclouds by using the passthrough filter provided by the pcl library and also maintain the order of the given clouds.
My current solution is as follows:

```
using point_type_colored = pcl::PointXYZRGB;
using point_cloud_colored = pcl::PointCloud<point_type_colored>;

point_cloud_colored::Ptr registration_util::pass_through_filter(
     const point_cloud_colored::Ptr& cloud_in, double p_t_x_min, double p_t_x_max,
     double p_t_y_min, double p_t_y_max, double p_t_z_min, double p_t_z_max)
{
     point_cloud_colored::Ptr filtered_cloud(new point_cloud_colored);
     *filtered_cloud = *cloud_in;
     pcl::PassThrough<point_type_colored> pass_filter;

     //filter x boundaries
     if (p_t_x_min != p_t_x_max)
     {
         pass_filter.setInputCloud(filtered_cloud);
         pass_filter.setFilterFieldName("x");
         pass_filter.setFilterLimits(p_t_x_min, p_t_x_max);
         pass_filter.filter(*filtered_cloud);
     }

     //filter y boundaries
     if (p_t_y_min != p_t_y_max)
     {
         pass_filter.setInputCloud(filtered_cloud);
         pass_filter.setFilterFieldName("y");
         pass_filter.setFilterLimits(p_t_y_min, p_t_y_max);
         pass_filter.filter(*filtered_cloud);
     }

     //filter z boundaries
     if (p_t_z_min != p_t_z_max)
     {
         pass_filter.setInputCloud(filtered_cloud);
         pass_filter.setFilterFieldName("z");
         pass_filter.setFilterLimits(p_t_z_min, p_t_z_max);
         pass_filter.filter(*filtered_cloud);
     }

     return std::move(filtered_cloud);
}
```

The input cloud has a defined width (= 1280) and height (=720) which means the point cloud is ordered. But the output cloud has only the height of one and a width of 92160 which means the cloud has lost its order due to downsampling.

How do I keep the original order of the input cloud?
If it is possible are there similar solutions for other downsampling methods like random filtering?

Comment: Hi MichaelN, welcome.. I'm not sure if i understand your issue. The code looks fine, you say there is only one point (pixel?) filtered from your original point cloud ? Maybe your min-max limits are set too narrow ? Can you tell some more about what you are trying to achieve with "keep the original height". You are filtering.. if it is an image you could e.g. make an empty image with the same size and just put the (filtered) pixels in the right place, but.. images are not point clouds.. images are output..

Comment: @Goodies Hi thank you for your reply.
Sorry for my poor articulation (I am somewhat new to the PCL). 
What i mean is the ordering of the incoming point clouds is ruined by the filter since the height of the output cloud is only 1 after the process. But if you ignore the order, the point clouds are just fine. It's just about the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the function [setKeepOrganized](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_filter_indices.html#a21eb00357056c0cc432cd03afa84d08c). Providing `true` will set each filtered point to `NaN` instead of removing the point.

You can also change the value to set it to with [setUserFilterValue](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_filter_indices.html#a9456a457b18c28b8dd6b07e970c16eba), but keeping it `NaN` has the benefit that other PCL algorithms won't consider these points for their algorithm.

Comment: I totally overlooked that. Thank you!